# Android <include> ListView not taking up its height

Tags: android, listview, include, height, fill-parent

I have a very strange problem here. In the following xml section I'm trying to use include:

> ```
> <!-- CONTENT -->
> <ScrollView
>   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>   android:fadingEdge="none">
>
>   <LinearLayout
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
>
>       <include android:id="@+id/summary"
>           layout="@layout/view_summary"
>           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>           android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
>
>   </LinearLayout>
>
> </ScrollView>
> ```

(the section is in a main linear layout with vertical orientation and both width and height set to fill parent)

The included xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/news_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/news_load_more"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Load more..."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the ListView is not taking up the whole height (the height of the screen), only the size of one single list item. I have tried setting layout parameters from code, but it didn't helped.

Any idea is welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: why do you wan to put ListView inside a scroll view???

Answer (score 1):

Don't put listview inside scrollview. Remove the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_weight="0"` to  `<Button android:id="@+id/news_load_more" ... />`  This will tell it that `<ListView android:id="@+id/news_list" ...>` is the one to be expanded to fill its parent while the button must not.

Answer (score -1):

Please changed android:layout_height="wrap_content" instead of android:layout_height="fill_parent"

only not changed ScrollView height property .

may be help to you.